# Ruby: Access return value of a method inside initialize

Tags: ruby, methods

I am trying to access the return value of

```
 def entries
   return lang # lang is a hash
  end
```

inside

```
def initialize
    @lang = Hash.new
    return entries
  end
```

But it is returning an empty hash.

At the end of the code, I have

```
@query = Book.new
@query.add('sea')
@query.include?("sea")
```

How do I get the stored value. So I can call `include?` on `@query` itself. Because right now it gives me an undefined method error.

But when I do-

```
@query = Book.new
@query.add('sea')
@query.entries.include?("sea")
```

It returns true.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to override the include? method, for example
def include?(value)
  @entries.include?(value)
end

Comment: yes I could do that. but wonder if there is some other way to do it.?

Comment: Without changing the logic of your class, I think that no.

Comment: -1. Too many unexplained constants/variables/methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that Book.new won't return the entries. It always returns a book instance. You can override the new method but then you can't access the book instance. Your best option is to delegate the include method to entries.

Comment: yep guess gonna have to do that :).